# Passing variables from one window to another is already declared

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering if it was possible to send variables from one window to another, the main one being already declared.

**For example** I have *`"Window1"`* click on the *"Add"* button and go to *`"Window2"`* in it I fill in the fields and when I click "Save" it sends the data to the datagrid that is in *`"Window1"`*.

**"Window1":**

[image: Window1]

Code DataGrid1 Window1:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Items" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="356" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text1" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Area01}" Width="130"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text2" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Area02}" Width="50"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text3" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Area03}" Width="50"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Image" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Area03}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Add" Click="OnDelete" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="OnDelete" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="OnDelete" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
```

Code of Button "Add": 
*I know it was very obvious but it was to make sure*

```
Window2 w = new Window2();
w.Show();
```

Click on the "Add" button and go to "Window2":

[image]

You have to send **an image** and **5 strings**.

I tried:

- Go through a file but in the image it gives error.
- Passing through objects I tried to call a function and passing, but
  it was already declared it was not enough.
- And I used this code but the problem is that if you have more than
  one window open, it gives an error.

  ((Window1)Application.Current.MainWindow).SendValues(*Image*,"","","");

If you could help me I would be very happy.

Sorry I'm not fluent in English.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is expose the variables you want to get back as properties of `Window2`.

For example, in `Window2` you could have:

```
public string String1 { get; set; }
public string String2 { get; set; }
public string String3 { get; set; }
```

In `Window2`, you would bind these properties to the UI, or set them via code. Then you can reference the properties like so:

```
//Your existing code in the add button's click event
Window2 w = new Window2();
w.ShowDialog();

//Accessing the properties after the window is shown
this.SomeProperty = w.String1;
this.DoSomethingWithString(w.String2);
```

Notice I used `ShowDialog`, not `Show`. `ShowDialog` pauses the calling code and continues after the `Window` closes. In the above code, the method would stop at `ShowDialog` until `w` closed, then would continue. See [Dialog boxes overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/dialog-boxes-overview) for more information.

If you want the user to be able to continue using the calling `Window1` while `Window2` is open, you could use `Show`, but then you would need to declare one or more events on `Window2` and add handlers from `Window1` to be notified when the variable you wanted had been changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by creating an overload method to your window, or just creating a public property that you can set to it before showing...  I will show both options though.

First, create a function in your first window that is expecting as input parameters the components you want. I will do based just on image and two strings, but they could be whatever you wanted.

```
    public void ThisMethodInFirstWindow(Image ImageFromThisForm, string firstText, string secondText)
    {
        // now in your first form, do whatever you need to with the now
        // available parameters coming from the second form.  You still should
        // validate nothing is NULL or empty or whatever rules you have...
    }
```

Now, in your second window, as stated, you could overload, or just create a public property as an "Action".  Its like a callback method.  You are just saying hey... when you need to, you can pass this action the values you want and it will use them for you...

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // declare an overloaded function to the window that accepts a function
    // but also calls its default constructor for InitializeComponent() in case
    // you have other preparation stuff going on in the window.
    public Window2(Action<Image, string, string> doWhatInOriginalWindow ) : this()
    {
        PassBackToMainWindow = doWhatInOriginalWindow;
    }

    public Action<Image, string, string> PassBackToMainWindow {get; set;}
}
```

Notice the property `PassBackToMainWindow` has a signature method that is expecting 3 parameters of an Image, string and string.  Notice also, the overloaded method to the window has the same Action declaration, and they all match the signature as created in the first window.

Now, we can call the window... both versions...

```
// Here, you are passing the METHOD name you want to handle the data to be added
// this uses the overload method
Window2 w = new Window2(ThisMethodInFirstWindow);
w.ShowDialog();
```

or

```
// this version creates window.  Specifically applies the action to tell what method
// you explicitly want called from within the second form, THEN show the window last
Window2 w = new Window2();
w.PassBackToMainWindow = ThisMethodInFirstWindow;
w.ShowDialog();
```

Finally, how do you use it.  In the Save button on your form, add the following for the click button action on the second window.  From the perspective of the second window, you have an action property. So just call it as if it was a method directly on the second form, but since it is an action that points to the first form, you are just passing the fields along for the ride and the first form gets them.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PassBackToMainWindow == null)
        return;

    PassBackToMainWindow(ImageFromThisForm, ThisWindow.Text1.Text, ThisWindow.Text2.Text);
}
```

Now, instead of having some massive set of parameters, if you have some structural class that has many properties to it, such as

```
public class MySampleThing
{
   public Image MyImageForWindow {get; set;}
   public string MyText1 {get; set;}
   public string MyText1 {get; set;}
}
```

Then you could just change the signature of the method and Action items to

```
public void SomeFunction( MySampleThing singleInboundParameter )
{
   // Now you can use EVERYTHING available on your object parameter
   var tmp = singleInboundParameter.MyImageForWindow;
   // etc.
}
```

And the Actions would be listed as

```
Action<MySampleThing>
```

And as a last, you could just pass back the entire Window2 such as

```
public void SomeFunction( Window2 entire2ndWindow )

Action<Window2>
```